# Android PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI throws IllegalArgumentException: column 'data1' does not exist

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

After a considerable amount of research I'm throwing this to see if it catches something.

Im trying to query the Android's `phone_lookup` table to try and get some extra data from a phone number (lookup_key, photo_thumb_uri, etc...).

Here's my query:

```
String[] projection = {Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? 
    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? 
    Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI : Contacts._ID};
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone.getNumber()));                                    
Cursor cs = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

In many cases, it works just fine and I get away with it. But unfornatunately, I've seen several reports of this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'data1' does not exist at 
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167) at 
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137) at 
android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366) at 
android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:373) at 
android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316) at
```

This is has only been reported for Android versions 4.2.2, 4.4.2 and 5.1, in that order of "frecuency precedence" (Not sure if it helps).

What leaves me thinking is... I'M NOT PROJECTING for any `data1` column. I'm not trying to get `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA` or `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number` (as I do in other queries, to other tables). So what am I missing? Are there any implicit joins I'm not seeing?

Comment: Did you find the reason? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Nope :(. Are you seeing the EXACT same error? On what devices and android versions? I honestly gave up on this one :(. It isn't that frequent, I'm guessing some manufacturers do custom stuff that get exposed in the versions I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same error happening on Xperia Z running Android 5.1.1.